# What is the minimum that I need to keg beer?

Tags: kegs, kegging

I currently only bottle beer, but I would like to have the flexibility of kegging beer to bring to a party from time to time.  I do not want to commit to a kegerator.  I will be happy to try to keep the beer on ice during the event.  What is the smallest amount of gear that I can get away with to accomplish this and about how much will it cost?

Comment: You'll want a way to get that keg cold while carbonating too, warm beer won't force carbonate as well.

Comment: how cold does the keg have to be?

Comment: Nothing more than the target temperature of the beer.  You can let it warm up after carbonating too, if you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this setup would be the minimum for 5 gallons of beer:

http://www.midwestsupplies.com/cornelius-keg-system-with-5-lb-co2-tank-comes-empty.html

A 5 gallon keg, CO2 tank, regulator, and tap.

Comment: I used this system ages ago, works a treat.